# Block all Windows network connections using Java

Tags: java, networking, firewall, jna

I'd like to program a little application in Java which would block all network connections (for whole os, not just VM) on demand. The application is for the Windows platform only and I would like to use Windows specific APIs.

I looked at the [Windows Firewall API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366449%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but didn't find anything useful. Also, I don't know how to call these APIs using JNA.

I'm asking you for a few pointers or examples for how I could accomplish these tasks:

- Using Windows Firewall or other APIs in Java using JNA or some other library (JNI is not preferred)
- Block/Unblock all connections

Comment: Is Java really needed here? Can't you directly call those Windows APIs using a batch/VB script or something?

Comment: or consider using [AutoIt v3](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: I don't think I want your app messing with my other network connections, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "netsh" command line, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875357
Invoke netsh command using the followinf syntax:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

But, I think, firewall is not what you need in this case. Here is the command line utility to enable/disable network interfaces for Windows: http://www.novell.com/communities/node/2338/network-configuration-command-line-control

Answer (score -1):

There is no API support for this in Java. You cannot do it.

Comment: The question is tagged with JNA which gives me the indication that he's looking for a Windows API to use in order to block the network connections and this lends me to believe that he realizes that there is no built in support in Java for this.